# Location of PHP error logs in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm currently experiencing routing issues, where various pages of my application are returning white pages.

Where are the PHP logs located within Homestead Vagrant so I can diagnose what's the issue?

I've checked `/var/log/` and I can only see a `php7.0-fpm.log` that relates to PHP, but nothing is generated within here when I read it.

Comment: Are you chmod 777 for storage and bootstrap folder?

Comment: Log file path: laravel root folder/storage/logs/laravel.txt

Comment: I am so disappointed in in Laravel Homestead. Getting it set up has taken me hours, and finally I can see my website in my browser, but I can only see a 500 error page, and I can't find the logs anywhere. Vagrant and Homestead have been a waste of my time so far. I'd love to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Ryan Try c9.io next time - Homestead was huge waste of time for me too.

Comment: I know this thread is a couple years old but fwiw I also ran into a few problems with setting up homestead, but it was well worth it. Your Google skills definitely have to be on point.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem too.

Finally I figured out that it was because my custom Laravel code (that I'd downloaded from my Bitbucket repo onto a new computer) included custom code in `bootstrap/app.php` at the `$app->configureMonologUsing` line, and **I hadn't properly set up a new `.env` file.**

I guess it can be dangerous / fragile to mess with the default logger.

But now that I fixed my `.env`, the logs correctly appear in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: This led me to the solution for my problem. I needed to copy the .env.example file to .env and configure my database settings. That cleared the 500 and Laravel told me to generate the app key and nicely provided a button on the page to do so.